# Is it possible to change the default InputView in MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, inputview

I would like to display a different view than the standard keyboard (a picker control, or a date picker, for example) when a text field becomes first responder (i.e. gets focus). This would be really nice, because currently I'm pushing a custom view which contains my picker control onto the navigation stack where the user chooses an option, and then hits an OK or Cancel button.

According to [the documentation for UITextField.InputView](http://go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=P%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField.InputView):

> Assigning a custom view to this
>   property causes that view to be
>   presented instead.

But, **It's read only!!!**

Is there a workaround for this? Do I need to implement a custom UITextField control and somehow override the InputView property? Do I need to call some kind of native function? I'd really love **not** to have to do either of those things... but if I have to, so be it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is slightly out of date.  There is a setter since MonoTouch 3.2.0.

Comment: I was using 3.1.3. I just got around to updating to 3.2.4, and it works now - thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

[Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627611/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-inputview-in-monotouch/4627895#4627895) will work for UIKeyboardType keyboards but as far as I'm aware (I could be wrong) you can't present a custom keyboard this way.

The only way I know how to present a custom keyboard is to override the InputView for the `UIViewController` you wish to present the input view.

```
UIView keyboardView;

public override UIView InputAccessoryView {
   get 
   {
       // create the view as you'd like here
       return keyboardView;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wire up the UITextField to handle the appropriate editing event and in the event handler select the [KeyboardType](http://go-mono.com/docs/monodoc.ashx?link=T%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIKeyboardType) you want.  If you don't need to dynamically set it then you can just set the property when you create the text field.

```
UITextField tf;
...
tf.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.PhonePad; // whatever kb you want
```